# Spring Batch AbstractPagingItemReader first reads all records and then process and writes

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am having a use case where in I am using AbstractPagingItemReader to make paginated calls.The use case is that reader should make an api call process and write immediately and this should continue until no more records are fetched by reader.

What currently is happening is that it accumulates all records first and then starts to process and write.

Elaborated Further :-
Say I want a total of 100 users in my destination.
For this I make 10 calls with page size of 10 (10*10).
The reader will first accumulate all 100 users calling api 10 times and then call the writer.
Instead i wanted to first send the response of first request to writer and then make second call and so on.

To make the 10 calls I intentionally added a for loop to iterate 10 times as else the code would have just made 1 fetch request and called writer and would have exited.

Comment: Please share your code. It could be that the chunk size is bigger than the page size, hence the reader will call make multiple calls (request multiple pages) to accumulate a chunk.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine ,i kept chunk size as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got solved when I implemented ItemReader .This lead to overriding of read method :-
`public class DataReader implements ItemReader{`